# Select on a table with 2 possible structures

Tags: sql-server, select, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write a query that will select data from a table. due to different versions of the database, there are 2 possible structures for the source table, where the newer version has 2 more fields than the old one.

I've tried identifying the older structure and replacing the columns with NULL and also tried writing 2 separate queries with and IF statement directing to the correct one. Neither of these solutions work and in both cases it seems that the SQL engine is failing on validating these 2 columns.

Examples of my attempted solutions:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM   sys.objects 
               WHERE  object_id = Object_id(N'[dbo].[Test2]') 
                      AND type IN ( N'U' )) 
  BEGIN 
      CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test2] 
        ( 
           [id]       [INT] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, 
           [statusid] [INT] NULL 
        ) 
  END 

go 

DECLARE @Flag INT = 0 

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 
          FROM   sys.columns 
          WHERE  NAME = N'TestId' 
                 AND object_id = Object_id(N'dbo.Test2')) 
  SET @Flag = 1 

--Solution #1
IF @Flag = 1 
  SELECT id, 
         statusid, 
         testid 
  FROM   dbo.test2 
ELSE 
  SELECT id, 
         statusid 
  FROM   dbo.test2 

--Solution #2
    SELECT id, 
           statusid, 
           CASE 
             WHEN @Flag = 1 THEN testid 
             ELSE NULL 
           END AS TestId 
    FROM   dbo.test2
```

Comment: "due to different versions of the database, there are 2 possible structures for the source table" - so have 2 different versions of the proc in each database!. That's pretty standard versioning.

Comment: There are 2 versions of the source database but just one version of the database I'm working on.

Comment: put the relevant procs in those databases and simply call from your database....

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Dynamic SQL` and generate the query accordingly depends on value of `@flag`

```
declare @sql    nvarchar(max)

select  @sql    = N'select id, statusid, '
                + case when @flag = 1 then 'testid' else 'NULL' end + ' as testid'
                + ' from dbo.test2'

print   @sql
exec    sp_executesql @sql
```

But it will not be that easy to code and maintain Dynamic Query if you have a complex query.

Comment: I was hopping to find a solution that did not require the use of dynamic SQL, but this is a good legitimate answer.
Thanks

Comment: And you're very right regarding the maintenance, that's why I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: i don't think there are any other possible solution other than `Dynamic SQL`